# Lagged-correlation between 2 Python Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I would like to get the lagged-correlation between 2 parameters that are in 2 different dataframes.
The 2 dataframes contain some meteorological data where the cols are the location (x,y) and the lines are one day in a year. (See an example on the image below)

[image: example of my dataframe]

What I want to use is :

```
df1.corrwith(df2.shift(i))
```

However, when using shift(50) for example, it computes the correlation between df1 and df2 that now has its 50 first lines filled with NaN.

My question is then : "Does it even make sense statistically to do this ?"
I am not sure how corrwith is working so I am a bit lost.

Thank you very much in advance for your help !!

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate on what you're trying to do in order to decide whether it makes sense. But the function is performance as expected because when you lag one signal vs. another, you're going to be getting null values (they don't exist). That being said, you can do a circular shift. (values at the end get prepended to the front)

Comment: For example : 
Dataframe 1 = precipitations;
Dataframe2 = soil moisture. 
Is there a lag-correlation between the two ? Meaning : has the precipitation an impact on the soil moisture later on ? 
WIth a simple correlation between my 2 dataframes, I have the correlation of prec-moisture at the same time in my time series. 

Is it somewhat clearer ?

Answer (score 0):

So yes, it makes sense and it's statistically valid. The p-values that are reported are only going to be adjusted by the number of non-null values that you have after the lag.